# Enthalpy vs Heat

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, chemical-engineering, energy

If we have a closed cylinder filled with a gas and we heat it, by $1^{st}$ law we have: $\Delta q=\Delta U$ (?) since $\Delta V$ = 0. But $\Delta H= \Delta U+ V. \Delta P$.

What does that difference between the enthalpy change and heat supplied physically signify in this case?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/296741/what-exactly-is-enthalpy